# Can I store a published vb.net windows form app in sharepoint

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

This seems real simple but Google is not very clear. I made a Vb.net app, works great on my desktop. I want to put it into SharePoint so others can download and use it. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not immediately. SharePoint blocks certain file types which you're going to have  to allow. You can find more about that [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262496.aspx) (note: you can pick the version of SharePoint you have just under the heading for relevant documentation).